# How to refer to component variable property in its template omitting variable name itself?

Tags: angular, typescript

If my component operates an object of such a class:

```
class Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: number;
}
```

how can I refer to its properties in the template in this way:

```
<p>{{firstName}}</p>
<p>{{lastName}}</p>
<p>{{age}}</p>
```

rather than mention the variable name every time (`{{person.firstName}}`, and so on)?

Answer (score 0):

That's not advised but since you are asking ...

```js
class MyComponent {
  constructor() {
    Object.assign(this, { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 42 });
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I would like to avoid mixing up the component and its model. I hoped there is some native solution to it.

Comment: There is some "native" solution but it requires a frickload of code, it involves structural directives with specific contexts, I would recommend you to avoid that.